# Automator: Change to selected directory and run shell script

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, automator, command-line

I'm trying to create a context menu command via Automator service. The context menu command will run a shell script to create some default documents in the given directory.

I wrote out the shell script which executes correctly when run from the target directory:

```
#!/bin/bash


touch History.markdown
touch Notes.markdown
touch Plan.markdown

touch ProjectName.tmproj

cat <<TEXT > ProjectName.tmproj
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>currentDocument</key>
    <string>Notes.markdown</string>
    <key>documents</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>filename</key>
            <string>Notes.markdown</string>
            <key>selected</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>filename</key>
            <string>History.markdown</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>filename</key>
            <string>Plan.markdown</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>openDocuments</key>
    <array>
        <string>History.markdown</string>
        <string>Notes.markdown</string>
        <string>Plan.markdown</string>
    </array>
    <key>fileHierarchyDrawerWidth</key>
    <integer>200</integer>
    <key>metaData</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>showFileHierarchyDrawer</key>
    <true/>
    <key>windowFrame</key>
    <string>{{113, 95}, {1230, 900}}</string>
</dict>
</plist>
TEXT
```

I then opened Automator and created a new service. I set the service to receive selected input of `folders` in `Finder`.

I then added the following to the top of my shell script to received the selected directory as standard input:

```
FolderPath=$1
$(cd $FolderPath)
```

The variable `FolderPath` definitely gets the current directory. I added a `say $FolderPath` to the shell script and it says out the entire path when run from the context menu command.

The problem is that when I try to change to the directory in the variable, nothing happens. I put another `say` command that spoke the command `pwd` after the directory change and it says that I'm at my user's root.

Is there something that automator does differently when dealing with shell scripts?

Here's a screen shot of the entire service.
[image]

I should also mention that I have tried to just concatenate the folder path and the file name that I've tried to create with the `touch` command and when I do so it only uses the string name of the file to create:

```
say "$FilePath/History.markdown" # only says "History dot markdown"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you use `$(cd $FolderPath)` instead of `cd $FolderPath`?

Comment: I tried `cd $FolderPath` first and it didn't work so I tried forcing the command with `$()` and just didn't pull it out after it still didn't work.

Comment: You can't *force* a command with `$()`, run it directly in `bash` to see what happens.

Comment: With some commands you can force it using `$()` as it runs the command within the parens in a subshell and returns the result (though looking back at my command now it wouldn't do anything with the cd command because the navigation's scope is the subshell). Either way, I did run it in bash and it works fine (I built it originally for bash). As a test just now, I wrote the following command which executes successfully when run from a shell: `say $(pwd)
FolderPath="/Volumes/Secure/TEMP/"
cd $FolderPath
say $(pwd)`. The same structure used in automator does not successfully change directory.

Comment: Sorry, I was running out of room in the last comment. If you create an automator service with just the steps: `

#!/bin/bash

say $(pwd)
FolderPath=$1
cd $FolderPath
say $(pwd)'
The finder will speak the same directory each time. The `cd` doesn't actually change directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is you have the input being passed to `stdin`. I don't know why that's the default, but you should be able to just change the popup menu in the top right to "as arguments." I did that and added `cd "$1"` to the top of the script and it worked.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for pointing that out. I switched it to `as arguments` and everything worked as it should. Thanks for the help!